# Run command at time of object creation

Tags: class, scheme, racket

I have following code for a simple class (stack):

```
#lang racket

(define stackClass%
  (class object% 
    (super-new)
    (init-field (mystack '(A B C)))      

    (define/public (push n)
      (set! mystack (cons n mystack)))

    (define/public (pop) 
      (cond [(empty? mystack)   #f]
            [else  (define res (car mystack))
                   (set! mystack (rest mystack))
                   res] ))

    (define/public (show)
      mystack)

    mystack   ; I want to output mystack at time of creation of class object; not working here; 

    )); end class; 


; USAGE:
(define sc (new stackClass%))
(send sc push 1)
(send sc push 2)
(send sc show) 
(send sc pop)
(send sc show)
```

Output:

```
'(2 1 A B C)
2
'(1 A B C)
```

I want to output mystack at time of creation of class object. However, it is not working in this code, though there is no error being shown.

Using following instead of `(init-field (mystack '(A B C)))` also does not help:

```
(init (L '(A B C)))
(define mystack L)
```

How can I run a piece of code at the time of class creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your code is running fine. In addition, "mystack" is being evaluated. However, it produces no output. If you want to display something, you can use one of a number of functions. Try replacing `mystack` with `(println mystack)` in your code.

Comment: I knew I was missing something very simple. Thanks.